# How can I forward my website local url link?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

everyone, I want to enter **www.tempsite.com** but in this site I define a website name is **sample**
I enter my site with this link : **www.tempsite.com/sample/index.aspx**.
But I want to enter just **www.tempsite.com** this and I want to see my site. How can I do that?And I do no want to people can see the index.**aspx** extension
thanks

Comment: I do not know correct terminology , please correct my title of question if it is wrong.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx

Comment: please give me some sample I cant understand from that link